# Remove table rows related to not highlighted word

Tags: jquery

There is a table, where each cell contains some words, part of them highlighted. For example, this instruction removes the row related to an highlighted word:

```
$(".highlightWord").closest('tr').remove();
```

Instead, I would want to resolve the inverse problem, i.e. to remove all rows that don't contain highlighted words.

I hope there is a genial person who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: is highlightWord class in td or tr ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("tr").not(":has(.highlightWord)").remove();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qDCQh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('your-table-select tr').not($(".highlightWord").closest('tr')).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$("td:not(.highlightWord)").closest('tr').remove();
```